# Pattern for deploying dashboards using kube prometheus stack's grafana dashboard sidecar

Tags: prometheus, grafana, kube-prometheus-stack

I am trying to get kube prometheus stack's grafana dashboard sidecar to deploy dashboards depending on the environment (dev, staging, prod, all environments). I can't quite figure out a good way to do this.

My folder structure currently looks like such:

```
kube-prometheus-stack
  charts
    grafana
      templates
        env
          dev
            dashboard1-cm.yaml
            dashboard2-cm.yaml
          staging
          prod
          all-environments
```

I'd like to deploy dev dashboards to dev, staging to staging and so on.

I've been browsing https://github.com/kiwigrid/k8s-sidecar but haven't been able to figure out a good pattern to handle this.

Curious how others are doing this.

Comment: Have you succeed with the solution?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried just one simple thing:

1. add one more folder for env-specific folder only

[image]

2. add the placement for the specific location of the dashboards in that folder to the specific `value-env.yaml`

   ```
   grafana:
       sidecar:
         dashboards:
           enabled: true
           label: grafana_dashboard
           annotations: {}
           multicluster: false
           alpha: true
   ```
3. In yaml associated with specific dashboard (`mqtt2.yaml`) I have

   ```
   {{- if $.Values.grafana.sidecar.dashboards.alpha }}
    ....
   {{- end }}
   ```

surronding previos config to exclude it if `.alpha` property isnt set

4. upgrading helm for the specific env with passing the specific config for that:

   ```
   helm -n monitoring upgrade prometheus ./ -f values-core.yaml -f values-alpha.yaml --recreate-pods
   ```

For me it works and now I'm able ho have different dashboards at the different envs. Also note, `dashboards-1.14` folder still have all dashboards being still deployed even after the sidecar configuration update, so move all dashboards from just `dashboards` to it, while have set up other folders to store data instead of generic just dashboards to some env-specific like mine `dashboards-alpha`.